# Python package/function to get percentage area covered by one polygon in another polygon using geo coordinates

Tags: python, geospatial

I am looking for a solution to find the percentage area covered by a polygon inside another polygon, from geo coordinates using python. 
The polygon can be either fully reside inside the other one or a portion of the second polygon.
Is there a solution to this. 
Please advice.

Answer (score 0):

Percentage is just area of intersection over area of the (other) polygon:
`area(intersection)/area(polygon2)`.

Basically any of geometry packages should be able to compute this, as they all support area and intersection functions: I think Geopandas, SymPy, Shapely (and others I missed) should be able to do this. There might be differences in supported formats.

You did not specify what Geo coordinates you use though. I think Geopandas and SymPy support only 2D maps (flat map) - meaning you need to use appropriate projection to get exact result, and Shapely works with spherical Earth model.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go, ready to use!

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

def overlap_percentage(outer_polygon, inner_polygon):
    """Calculates the percentage of a polygon that overlaps with another polygon."""

    outer_polygon = Polygon(outer_polygon)
    inner_polygon = Polygon(inner_polygon)

    ratio = outer_polygon.intersection(inner_polygon).area / inner_polygon.area
    return round(ratio * 100, 2)

outer_poly = [(0, 0), (0, 2), (2, 2), (2, 0)]
inner_poly = [(1, 1), (1, 3), (3, 3), (3, 1)]
print(overlap_percentage(outer_poly, inner_poly))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).